# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type { ASP.NET MVC }

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i having error throw on View page and i think i am passing wrong type, can anybody please correct me - thanks.

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[App.Domain.Model.Interface.IPerson]' but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[App.Domain.Service.PersonService]'.

MyService looks like this....

```
namespace App.Domain.Service
{
    public class PersonService :  IPersonService
    { 
        private IPersonRepository _personRepository;
        public PersonService(IPersonRepository personRepository)
        {
            _personRepository = personRepository; 
        }

        public List<IPerson> GetPerson()
        {            
            return _personRepository.GetHost();
        } 
    }
}
```

myView look like this...

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" 
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<App.Domain.Service.PersonService>>" %>
```

my controller look like this...

```
 public ActionResult GetPersons()
        {
            IPersonRepository personRepo = new PersonRepository();
            PersonService person = new PersonService(personRepo);
            IList<IPerson> p  = person.GetPerson(); 
            return View(p);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending the wrong type to the View() 
In your View decleration says App.Domain.Service.PersonService, but in your View you are sending it a View(IPerson).
If you want to send an IPerson to your view the tag should read like:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<App.Domain.Model.Interface.IPerson>>" %>
```

Comment: why i dont see the "App.Domain.Model.Interface.IPerson" in view data class? means...when i create a View page (right click in the controller and click on Add View) and i select "create strongly typed view" but i see all my model/repository classes but i dont see anything related with "Interface" why is that?

Comment: Not really sure why they dont include Interfaces, I actually haven't tried to use one through the view wizard before.
That would be a good follow up question though.